# Should I use a <div> instead of <p> when it contains a list (<ul>)?

Tags: html

On this snippet:

```
<p>
  <ul>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
  </ul>
</p>
```

IntelliJ 10.5 warns that the closing `</p>` tag "matches nothing`.

I see that `<p>` is only supposed to contain "[Phrasing content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Content_categories#Phrasing_content)". So, should I replace the `<p>` with a `<div>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. `<p>` isn't supposed to contain lists, it's intended for inline content. `<div>` is right here if you're just looking to wrap the list in an element.

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```